# Magento 2 show custom option price in order email

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento-1.8

I have tried to set custom option price when order is placed the price should be stored in sales_order_item table in custom_option column and tried to create plugin for this but the plugin is not working.
I have done debug and found that COre magento custom option data is set from this abstract class :

This is magento core function behavior of custom option.

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php**

```
/**
     * Prepare additional options/information for order item which will be
     * created from this product
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOrderOptions($product)
    {
        $optionArr = [];
        $info = $product->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest');
        if ($info) {
            $optionArr['info_buyRequest'] = $this->serializer->unserialize($info->getValue());
        }

        $optionIds = $product->getCustomOption('option_ids');
        if ($optionIds) {
            foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
                $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
                if ($option) {
                    $confItemOption = $product->getCustomOption(self::OPTION_PREFIX . $option->getId());

                    $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                        ->setOption($option)
                        ->setProduct($product)
                        ->setConfigurationItemOption($confItemOption);

                    $optionArr['options'][] = [
                        'label' => $option->getTitle(),
                        'value' => $group->getFormattedOptionValue($confItemOption->getValue()),
                        'print_value' => $group->getPrintableOptionValue($confItemOption->getValue()),
                        'option_id' => $option->getId(),
                        'option_type' => $option->getType(),
                        'option_value' => $confItemOption->getValue(),
                        'custom_view' => $group->isCustomizedView(),                        ];
                }
            }
        }

        $productTypeConfig = $product->getCustomOption('product_type');
        if ($productTypeConfig) {
            $optionArr['super_product_config'] = [
                'product_code' => $productTypeConfig->getCode(),
                'product_type' => $productTypeConfig->getValue(),
                'product_id' => $productTypeConfig->getProductId(),
            ];
        }

        return $optionArr;
    }
```

In this core file if i add this key and value in existing array then i am able to get price in transactional email.

```
'price' => $group->getOptionPrice($confItemOption->getValue(), 0)
```

Could any one suggest that how could we save custom option price in order and get it in emails.

Answer (score 0):

For temporary fix i have used the below code in block and used in email items phtml file.

Please Post answer if there is better way available to achieve it.

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml**

```
/**
     * Returns array of Item options
     *
     * @param object $_item
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItemOptions($_item)
    {
        $result = [[]];
        if ($options = $_item->getProductOptions()) {
            if (isset($options['options'])) {
                $result[] = $options['options'];
            }
            if (isset($options['additional_options'])) {
                $result[] = $options['additional_options'];
            }
            if (isset($options['attributes_info'])) {
                $result[] = $options['attributes_info'];
            }
        }
        return array_merge(...$result);
    }

    /**
     * Return option price
     *
     * @param [] $option
     * @return int | bool
     */
    public function getCustomOptionPrice($option)
    {
        $price = null;
        if (isset($option['option_value'])) {
            $optionValueIds = explode(',', $option['option_value']);
            if (!empty($optionValueIds)) {
                foreach ($optionValueIds as $key => $value) {
                    $select = $this->resourceConnection->select()->from(
                        ['potp' => $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_option_type_price')],
                        [
                            'potp.price'
                        ]
                    )->where('potp.option_type_id = ?', $value);
                    $result = $this->resourceConnection->fetchRow($select);
                    if ($result && isset($result['price'])) {
                        $price += $result['price'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $price;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = $option['option_value'];
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$product->setIsSuperMode(true);
```